# Run As Application on Android for Eclipse installs app but doesn't run it and it doesn't appear as an icon

Tags: android, sdk, adt, samsung-mobile

I haven't dealt with Android recently so I've updated my SDK and ADT plugin (no more updates available). I'm running Eclipse Juno. I created a new project and when I Run As Android Application it installs on my phone but doesn't run or appear as an icon.

I have intent filter in the manifest as some people have offered that as a solution, no difference:

[image]

The build log and target API

[image]

[image]

My phone is an old Samsung 3 and it's running 4.3. Could this be an issue? I'm updating it now but it's taking a while.

Anything else I should check?

Comment: whats your minimum buid target? Normally after install the app should load up on phone. does it?

Comment: Where can I find the min build target, all I have is the min and target SDK shown in the manifest and then Android 5 checked as the build target. No, that app doesn't load after install as it has always done before. So something has happened in the update process.

Comment: try emulator? (i know its terrible and slow)

Comment: Doesn't even show on the emulator. I set it up as a Android 5.0 AVD and no luck

Comment: i would clean project, try then. 

Or delete gen folder then try then. (unless you tried these?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your `intent filter` inside `<activity>` tag in `Manifest` file

```
   <activity
        android:name="TestHome">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```